# Fastest way to look up a coordinate in the database

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Let's say I have a grid of squares, each with their coordinates (x and y). They all have an attribute that's stored in a database.

Would it be faster to store and look up that attribute like this:

```
SELECT * FROM asd WHERE x=1 AND y=-5
```

*or*

```
SELECT * FROM asd WHERE id='1_-5'
```

so basically joining the coordinates with an underscore for it to become a single string. Is it faster or slower?
Using PostgreSQL if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely your first approach.

Searching for integers is always faster than searching for strings. Besides it's bad practice to store multiple values in one column.

Also, please note that if these columns are critical for searching, you can (nay, need) define them as [indexes](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-indexes-sql-tutorial/).

Comment: Consider a multi-column index on (x,y) for the particular case.